# What version of Clockworkmod should I be using on my Galaxy Tab 2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I have been trying to install Cyanogenmod on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (SGH-1497) (AT&T) over the last few days and I keep getting stuck installing CWM Recovery. I have been able to successfully root the device, but I can't seem to find the right recovery version to use.

I have tried using:

- [koush's ClockworkMod Recovery](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-6.0.2.3-p5100.img) as instructed on the [CyanogenMod
  Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_p5100)
- CWM Touch 6.0.1.2 for [GT-p5100](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1842246)
- philz_touch_5.03.7-p5100.tar.md5
- ROM Manager installed via Google Play

After attempting to install, I either can't boot into recovery mode at all (the screen goes blank after I see the blue "booting into recovery" text on the Samsung screen) or I just end up at the stock recovery screen.

I have tried installing using both Linux Mint (following the CyanogenMod Wiki instructions) and Windows using Odin.

I have read several different guides on installing CWM and Cyanogenmod on my device, but they all seem to have different information and I am having a hard time figuring out which ROMs I should actually be using.

I would really appreciate some guidance on this.

Comment: Have you tried installing TWRP through ROM Manager?  That's the recovery that I have had the least problems with.